# Putting a bar over the variable not the argument or the space between them

Tags: bar

I am trying to put the bar on the variable but I either get it on the argument with \bar command or over the whole with \overline.
The expression is. Look especially at the derivative and s:

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\bar{x_{1}(\tau)}}{d\tau}=\quad&\bar{x_{1}}\left[\bar{r_{1}}\left(1-\bar{x_{1}}-\bar{\eta_{12}}\bar{x_{2}}-\bar{\eta_{13}}\bar{x_{3}}-\bar{\eta_{14}}\bar{x_{4}}\right)-\bar{f_{11}}\bar{y_{1}}-\bar{f_{12}}\bar{y_{2}} \right] +\bar{s_{i}(\tau)},\quad \bar{x_{1}(0)}>0\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: it is hard to debug if you only post a fragment, not a test docuemnt,  and it is not clear what output you want. Are you looking for `\bar{x}_{1}(\tau)` instead of `\bar{x_{1}(\tau)}`  ??

Comment: How about something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVGSU.png) instead (using `\bar{x}_1` rather than `\bar{x_1}`)?

Comment: @ Werner  Thats what I wanted actually.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  using \bar{x}_{1}(\tau) is good but the bar is little bit to the right and I want it exactly over.

Comment: @F.O: I used the same suggestion as David mentioned. The `\bar` is pushes slightly to the right since math variables are set with a slant.

Comment: @Werner  ,I thought that it was different ,sorry. Here texstudio just gives med \bar{x_{1}(\tau)}.

Comment: texstudio is not involved, that is just the editor you are using to write the file.  Why are you putting the whole `x_{1}{\tau)` construct inside the argument of `\bar` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle because that is what texstudio  suggest when I write \bar . It is good for fast writing but it is not what I want

Comment: @F.O it is just an editor, you don't have to type what it suggests. (how can it suggest that you enter `x_{1}{\tau)` not just `x` as the argument if you have not yet typed either and have just typed `\bar` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\bar` places an accent over the argument supplied (`\overline` is similar but uses a drawn rule of arbitrary length rather than a fixed width accent.

here you want x̄  so `\bar{x}`  with just `x` in the argument, not `\bar{x_{1}{\tau)}`